# Как удалить поле из объектов внутри объекта MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Есть объект

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fe571983fb2241d58c3cc8b"),
    "counters" : {
        "Warning" : {
            "value" : 0,
            "activeEntitiesIds" : []
        },
        "Ignore" : {
            "value" : 0,
            "activeEntitiesIds" : []
        },
        "Null" : {
            "value" : 0,
            "activeEntitiesIds" : []
        },
        "Extinction" : {
            "value" : 0,
            "activeEntitiesIds" : []
        },
        "Error" : {
            "value" : 0,
            "activeEntitiesIds" : []
        }
    },
    "stateGetDateTime" : ISODate("2020-12-25T04:59:06.577Z"),
    "_class" : "Subsystem"
}
```

Как можно удалить поля **activeEntitiesIds** сразу во всех объектах коллекции?

Думал сделать вот так, но почему-то не работает

```
db.subsystems.find().forEach(function(subsystem) {
    db.subsystems.update({_id:subsystem._id},
    {
        $unset:
        {
            "counters.$[].activeEntitiesIds" : 
            {
                $exists : true
            }
        }
    })
});
```